# Xamarin библиотеки для работы с Excel

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Подскажите пожалуйста какие библиотеки существуют для чтения/записи данных в excel документ?

Рекомендуют в основном *Syncfusion*, но он слишком дорогой (995$ в месяц для одного человека)

Есть какие то более скудные, но бесплатные библиотеки для работы с excel в Xamarin?

Может быть даже без кросс-платформенности, а только для Android, но на C#

Comment: Ну, вы поищите на GitHub, попробуйте разные. Я не спец, но например, [вот так поискать можно](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=excel&type=Repositories), их полно. Суть в том, что вам достаточно найти любую библиотеку соответствующую .NET Standard, такая библиотека точно будет кросс-платформенной, в том числе в Xamarin заведётся. К примеру, самая первая из поиска [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader). Написано, что соответствует .NET Standard 2.0

Answer (score 1):

- Старая и добрая **NPOI** https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi
- OpenXMl https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK